# Trying to 'undo' several CSS options with an inline statement

Tags: css, html-lists, inline-styles

I'm trying to 'undo' the style in an unnumbered list by putting an inline style statement in the 'li' tags.  I have everything looking the way I want except that I'm missing the bullet.

Below is the original CSS and my inline style options to overwrite them:

```
#account_header li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
    border-top: 1px solid #888888;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    color: #AA2222;
    font-family: "arial","helvetica";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Here's what I have inside my 'li' tag:

```
<li style="border: none;display: block;margin: 0;overflow: hidden;padding: 0;list-style:disc outside none;">
```

Thanks in advance...I've wasted plenty of time on this already!

Comment: Yes (sorry I wasn't too clear)...how do I get my bullets back?  I thought the "list-style:disc outside none;" would have done it.  The bullets don't show up at all.

Comment: Oh, hmm, it would seem that your zero margin and padding are causing your bullet to be hidden because it's `outside`.

Comment: BoltClock is right. You should set the margins back to what they would have been without the original stylesheet! To see what the defaults are, create a new HTML file without any styles, and inspect the ul and li elements.

Comment: It turned out to be the overflow-* options.  I'll explain as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone's going to believe this one, but it turned out to be the overflow-x and overflow-y options.  They were set to 'hidden,' and I had to look in the "computed" tab in Firebug to see it (I'm kind of a CSS newbie, so I've never heard of these before).  Basically, I took Mr Lister's suggestion to do an extremely simple list, copied the computed styles into text files and used UltraStudio's compare feature to see the difference.

I wish there was an easier way to set things back to default!

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
<li style="border: none;display: list-item;margin: 0;padding: 0;visibility: visible;overflow-y: visible;overflow-x: visible;list-style:disc outside none;" >
```

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: block;` and `overflow: hidden;` from your inline CSS and it will work.

Comment: The default styles for `<li>` elements are `display: list-item;` and `overflow: visible;`.